# How to compress extension for magento

Tags: magento

I have a extension ready to use in magento but when i compress my files magento show the follow error:

`CONNECT ERROR: Unsupported resource type`

I trying to compress trough the mac terminal using the next command:

`tar -zcvf 99minutos-2.0.1.tgz 99minutos-2.0.1`

But if I download an extension from freegento, I can install any package that i want.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

use below command

```
tar -zcvf 99minutos-2.0.1.tar.gz 99minutos-2.0.1
```